# Why I get "ImportError" only when I run a python script?

Tags: python, pip

I have a Python script where I import `datadog` module. When I run `python datadog.py`, it fails with `ImportError: cannot import name statsd`. The script starts with following lines:

```
import os
import mysql.connector

from time import time
from datadog import statsd
```

Actual error messages are following:

```
$ python /mnt/datadog.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/datadog.py", line 5, in <module>
    from datadog import statsd
  File "/mnt/datadog.py", line 5, in <module>
    from datadog import statsd
ImportError: cannot import name statsd
```

But when I'm in Python shell (started by `python` command), I can successfully run `from datadog import statsd`. What's the difference here?

By the way, I have proper Python packages installed in my computer:

```
$ pip freeze | egrep 'datadog|mysql'
datadog==0.17.0
mysql-connector==2.1.6

$ python --version
Python 2.7.5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your script is named `datadog.py`. So when it imports the module `datadog`, it imports itself.

Comment: Thanks! The filename was actually the cause of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

First install statsd by

```
pip install statsd
```

then do

```
import statsd
```